# Combine ngRepeat and conditional directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to learn some AngularJS for a project. In my model I have a list of elements that can be of different types. Now I want to show them in a table that looks similar to this example:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>nameA</td><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>         <!-- elements of type A -->
  <tr><td>nameB</td><td colspan="2">...data...</td></tr>  <!-- elements of type B -->
  <tr><td>nameC</td><td>...</td><td>...</td></tr>         <!-- elements of type A -->
</table>
```

If the element is of type A, it should be displayed like the first and third table row, if it is of type B, it should be displayed like the second table row.

How do I achieve this with AngularJS? I started with something like the following:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="elem in data.elements | orderBy:'name'">
    <td>{{ elem.name }}</td><td>...</td><td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But now all the table rows have the same format of course. I'm not sure how to combine this with some type of conditional directive to use different templates for the table row, depending on `elem.type`. I would need something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="elem in data.elements | orderBy:'name'">
    <pseudo-tag ng-if="elem.type == 'typeA'">
      <td>{{ elem.name }}</td><td>...</td><td>...</td>
    </pseudo-tag>
    <pseudo-tag ng-if="elem.type == 'typeB'">
      <td>{{ elem.name }}</td><td colspan="2">...data...</td>
    </pseudo-tag>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What is the AngularJS-y way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need a `pseudo-tag` because `ng-if` can be applied directly to `td`.  Something like this should work:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="elem in data.elements | orderBy:'name'">
    <td ng-if="elem.type == 'typeA' || elem.type == 'typeB'">{{ elem.name }}</td>
    <td ng-if="elem.type == 'typeB'" colspan="2">...data...</td>
    <td ng-if="elem.type == 'typeA'">...</td>
    ...
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I suppose this is the way to do it although I find it somewhat less clear than if you could just give different templates for the table row, depending on the currently iterated value.